# React Native Module Callback returns nothing

Tags: javascript, java, android, module, react-native

I am trying to get values from my java module to my js but my callback funtion returns nothing.

**My module method:**

```
@ReactMethod
public void foo(Integer stateNum, Callback func){
    final Integer num = stateNum;
    final Callback funcCallback = func;
    try{
        funcCallback.invoke(num);
    }catch (Exception e){}
}
```

**Then I call it on my js:**

```
showTest = () => {
    55,
    test.foo( (num) => {
        this.setState({ number1: num, number2: 200 })
    } );
}
```

So, when I run the `showTest` function, the state `number1` is not updated but state `number2` becomes 200, since I passed the value 200 directly from my js code. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Don't you need to pass 55 into `foo` before the lambda? like `test.foo(55, (num) => {<code>})`?

Answer (score 1):

I was passing the argument at the wrong place and I also had forgoten to recompile the whole project. The application wasn't warning me about the arguments because I was simply reloading it instead of recompiling it.